# Does next auth support authentication using phone numbers?

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth

Does next auth support authentication using phone numbers?

I am trying to implement Auth in my next.js app and I want to support phone authentication. Does [NextAuth.js](https://next-auth.js.org/) support authentication using phone numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's whatever you've set up your OAuth provider to handle. your provider will be the place for types of logins and restrictions.